# Revert React component to default props

Tags: reactjs

In React.js, is there a way to revert all props to their values in `getDefaultProps()`?

I assume this could be controlled by using `state` instead, which I'm open to. I'm trying to see if I can just toggle between default props and an updated prop value without having `states`, per se.

Comment: I think you are probably right and should just use state since it should be fairly simple to have something called setState(this.getInitialState()).

Comment: Changing the props from inside a component is an insane idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use [replaceProps(this.getDefaultProps())](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replaceprops) if you want to reset the props.

Using `setProps` will keep any other existing keys that's already on `props` as it merges the new `props` object with the old `props` object.

Mutating props however is not exactly what they are there for and whatever you're doing should be done with state instead.